# How to clear ClassCastException in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
public List<LogLineEntry> query(){

    List<LogLineEntry> timeRange = new ArrayList<LogLineEntry>();
       Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
        Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress((TransportAddress) new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));

        SearchResponse sResponse = null;
        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("lineNumber").from(100).to(200);

        while(sResponse== null|| sResponse.getHits().hits().length != 0){
            int scrollSize=200, i=0;
            sResponse = client.prepareSearch("jsonlogpage")
                    .setTypes("jsonlog")
                       .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                       .setSize(scrollSize)
                       .setFrom(i * scrollSize)
                       .execute()
                       .actionGet();

            for(SearchHit hit : sResponse.getHits()){
                timeRange.add(hit); //add() shows error
            }
            i++;
        }
        return timeRange;

}
```

I'm using Search Response. I got an error in add().

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.elasticsearch.search.internal.InternalSearchHit cannot be cast to com.example.elasticsearch.LogLineEntry

LogLineEntry is a pojo class.My list is created for LogLineEntry, hit variable belongs to searchHit. So I can't add searchHit variable into List. How can I resolve this?

Comment: whatever values you needed from hit take it from the hit variable and create new `LogLineEntry` inside the for loop and set that value to the LnLineEntry object then add that object to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert each `SearchHit` to a `LogLineEntry` instance. You cannot just add a `SearchHit` instance into a `List` declared to contain `LogLineEntry` instances.

So inside your for-loop you need to create a new instance of `LogLineEntry` and populate it with fields you find in each `SearchHit` instance.

```
        for(SearchHit hit : sResponse.getHits()){
            LogLineEntry entry = new LogLineEntry();
            // populate your new instance
            entry.setXyz(hit.getXyz());
            // do this for each field

            // add the instance to the list
            timeRange.add(entry);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Val

When I create entry.setXyz(hit.getXyz()); 

Error shows add cast to hit
entry.setLineNumber(((LogLineEntry) hit).getLineNumber());

Is this correct?

Comment: No, `entry.setLineNumber(hit.getSource().get("lineNumber"))`

Comment: setLineNumber datatype is long. it shows error.. can i use entry.setLineNumber((long) hit.getSource().get("lineNumber")); or should I change long to Object in pojo class?

Comment: Im sry to disturb u. Now also error that Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long, I've no int variables.

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a short Java crash course to learn about the language basics before diving into more complex stuff :-)

Comment: I agree. I do it Sir.